# how to make realtime update chart like in package express-status-monitor?

Tags: socket.io, chart.js

chart looks like below from [THIS GIF](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/aed7a6d40880b02a4a0a09587e69f0e85df78a4127b87b7a6bcbcb80b1efd46a/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4148697a4557712e676966) (image taken from https://github.com/RafalWilinski/express-status-monitor)

Like the gif above in the chart there is a description of the update time. And the data I want to use is from api.

Might be able to use chartjs and socket.io. How to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time, a new value is available, add it to `dataset.data`. As soon as a certain limit of values is reached, remove the oldest value through [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). Once `dataset.data` is updated, you need to invoke `chart.update()`.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works. Note that this code simulates the API using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

```js
var chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      borderColor: 'black',
      pointRadius: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'second',
          displayFormats: {
            second: 'h:m:s a'
          }
        },
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 3,
          maxRotation: 0
        }
      },
      y: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

var maxValues = 20;
setInterval(() => {  
  const data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  const v = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);  
  if (data.length >= maxValues) {
    data.shift();
  }
  data.push({ x: new Date(), y: v });
  chart.update();
}, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@1.0.0"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```